# How can I test that my UncaughtError handler is registered and working properly?

Tags: actionscript-3, tdd, flexunit

I have a logger which is supposed to catch uncaught error, and send the tracestack to a server.

I'm trying to write unit tests to make sure this works.  However, when I throw an error or errorEvent in my test classes, the FlexUnit Runner catches the error and doesn't let the test continue.

How can I unit test this?

Comment: Just throw another custom error event from there and catch that yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to my problem was to call `event.preventDefault();` when the error was caught.
This prevents the normal behavior of the error to happen, allows my custom events and unit tests to run.